# When is it more beneficial to have Ghost over Flash?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always thought that the [Ghost](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost) Summoner Spell was essentially the more "noob" version of [Flash](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Flash).  Recently, however, I have seen several pro-level games (MLG, PAX, etc.) where the pros do indeed get `Ghost` instead of `Flash`.  I don't understand the logic behind this and was hoping someone could enlighten me.  I've seen it a couple times, but the champion I specifically remember it on was a Shen.

The only thing I could think of was that Shen can already use `Taunt` to get over walls and obstacles, so perhaps `Ghost` would generate more distance in the long run... But even this seems like a stretch.

Thus the question: When and why is it more beneficial to get [Ghost](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost) over [Flash](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Flash)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I think about it is like this:

- if your champion has a snare/root/disable/whatever, then Flashing in range and using it (pretty much) guarantees you can keep hitting them for a good while at least. Think Darius and his W-E combo, you can Flash in range of a champion, pull him to you and snare, then just keep hitting him.
- if however your champion has no such disable, Flashing alone will get you one hit, maybe an autoattack too, then they run away. Here Ghost is more beneficial because you can keep chasing them. Shyvana is a very good example of this, although I like Ghost on Fiora also because her sprint ability is kind of short duration compared to the CD and she has nothing else.

You should however consider that Exhaust might be a better choice over Ghost for chasing/ganking purposes where Flash isn't "the right choice", because in addition to the snare, it also nerfs their damage output, so you can use it as a peel for your carries (or just straight dueling). I use Exhaust on both Nocturne and Shyvana for this purpose.

The argument above that Ghost is good at escaping... I don't know about that. You never really leave melee range if they snare you during it, whereas Flash opens a gap for you to let your snares run out and stops damage income cold. Ghost is also a one trick pony, whereas Flash can net you a huge tactical advantage by Flashing over walls that champions without Flash would have to otherwise slowly run around, or lets you escape turret damage instantly etc etc.

Try them all in my opinion, you'll get the hang of their strengths and weaknesses after some amount of games. I'll tell you that I miss Flash the most when I run Ghost or (more often) Exhaust, but I'd still never run a Flash Shyvana.

Comment: I run ghost a lot on champs when I go top. On someone like singed, or voli, where chasing someone down is very important

Comment: True, but Exhaust would work just as well on Voli for example. Singed is different because he wants to run from everyone, just out of reach of them (to hit them with his cloud), but Voli only wants to close the gap and do his little punt.

Answer (score 3):

There are only very few Champions where Ghost has an advantage above Flash, mostly champions that have an ability that is very similar or champions that have abilities that prevent them from getting stunned or snared.

The champion that is most often used with Ghost in highest level play is Olaf. His high base movement speed and slowing axe, as well as his Ultimate of course which prevents any crowd control effects, make it easy to escape dangerous situations so Ghost allows Olaf to chase down opponents more easily.

Other champions that are sometimes used with Ghost are Master Yi and Tryndamere which both have abilities similar to Olafs Ragnarok.

In general, Ghost has the main advantage of giving you a lot more chasing power which is especially useful for melee bruiser champions. Flash gives you an escape with the advantage that you can use it across walls, making escaping and positioning a lot easier for squishier champions like AD or AP carries.

Before you now run off and use Ghost on every Bruiser, note that Ghost does not prevent crowd control effects so if the enemy has any slow, you still won't be able to reach the enemy carry and you won't even have the option of escaping that you would have with Flash.

The only champions i would build with Ghost are the above mentioned Olaf, Yi and Tryndamere. All others should always have Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is by no means a 'noob' skill; however, I tend to only use it when I go top. I also tend to couple ghost with teleport so that my champion can be all over the map.

Advantages of ghost:

- Sustained speed boost
- If you have wards out, flash is better. If you have wards out, you can push and run back a little easier
- You can fly around the map to help out in team fights, support towers, etc (couples really well with teleport)
- For shen, rammus, singed, voli, - where you need to chase someone down and taunt/fling; ghost is better IMO
- Ghost is easier to use than flash (in a vacuum; I've personally attempted to flash over a wall and not made it =P )

Advantages of flash:

- Instant short boost
- Has a surprise factor for ganks (malphite for example can couple a flash + ult to quickly gank someone from out of a bush)
- can use walls to escape ganks
- can be used to dodge skill shots

Side-note: Ghost on singed with a rylai's crystal scepter and his ult makes for an entire team that cannot move :)

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is Better when you can do a similar move with a skill... Like a skill shot dash. 
The main purpose of flash is to get in or out a some situation very quickly...Engage or disengage

But if you have a skill allowing to do that, like Shen taunt or ezreal Arcane shift you can swap the flash for ghost wich will give you in addition to you skill a great escape/engage

In my opinion take sumonner's spell that gives you something you don't have.

I mostly use flash on squishy champions who needs to NOT BE CAUGHT ;-)

Few example :

Yi has Ghost like ult dans can dash the enemy to engage but no CC and no escape so ghost useless flash if you want to be safe exaust i you whant some CC

Singed Very tanky need to be chased without outranging the chaser to bait ==> Ghost OP :-D

Tryndamere Spin = Flash in or out => Ghost

Ezreal Shift = flash => ghost

Graves Quickdraw = flash => Ghost but very short range so it depends if the eneny team has a lot of thing to get to you or not :-D

Heracrim => charge = ghost // Ult = flash  ==> Exaust but ghost is so great cause it increase your damages with passive.

Volibear => Rolling thunder = ghost // Roar = exaust ==> Flash

Comment: You run Ghost on an AD carry?